# The Coin Collector's Problem

Tags: algorithm

I can not understand package-merge algorithm.
Can anyone explain package-merge algorithm step by step please?
How we package and how we merge?
Is there any other optimal algorithm for solving coin collector's problem?

Comment: Some background on the Coin Collector's Problem and 'package-merge' for anyone interested: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package-merge_algorithm

Answer (score 5):

This is a code-free answer: I'm going to try and explain the method using some example situations, and hope it can be intuited from them as I generalise it.  Sorry it's quite long, but if you read it through methodically it should all make sense.

Let's say a coin collector has two sets of coins: a set of dollar coins and a set of half dollar coins.  However, the coin collector values each coin differently based on, say, the date it was minted.  Some are very rare and so are more valuable.

Now, the situation is: he has no ordinary money except for his valuable coins, and he needs to use them to buy something at a store, where the clerk at the counter will only take them at their standard value.  But as he values his collection, he wants to use the least valuable set of coins he can to make the payment.

So let's say he has 7 dollar coins and 5 half dollar coins, and he wants to buy something worth 4 dollars.  A simplistic solution would be to take just his dollar coins and rank them by value, select the 4 least valuable, and hand them over, pocketing the remaining 3 dollar coins, which are the most valuable ones.

But then he realises that if he takes two half dollars and "packages" them together, he can treat the package as a new dollar-sized coin.  To the clerk at the counter it's worth a dollar, but to the collector it's worth the combined value of the two individual half dollars he used.

A better strategy then is to look at his half-dollars, take the cheapest two, package them together as a new dollar "coin", and add ("merge") it into his set of dollars.
So now he has 8 (7+1) dollar-sized coins/packages and 3 (5-2) half dollars.

This step can be repeated once more, and now he has 9 dollar-sized coins/packages, and 1 remaining half dollar that cannot be packaged with anything else.  Since this is his most valuable half dollar, he realises that he should not use it and pockets it again, effectively removing it from the problem.

Now he just has a set of 9 dollar-sized coins/packages.  He sorts them by value, selects the 4 that are least valuable, and hands them over to the clerk, pocketing the remaining (most valuable) coins.

To generalise slightly: imagine he also has some quarters with him.  Before packaging the half dollar coins, the he must first package the quarters into half-dollar packages (selecting the cheapest pairs in turn, discarding the most valuable remainder, if there is one), and then merge them into the set of half dollar coins.

Hypothetically there could be lesser denominations: 1/8th dollars, 1/16th dollars, etc.  As long as they are negative powers of two the strategy can be generalised: sort the coins of least denomination, package them, merge the packages into the set of the next smallest denomination, and continue until you have only dollar-sized coins/packages.

(There's one other case that's worth considering: if the asking price is not a round dollar figure, e.g. 7 1/4 dollars.  In this case, before packaging the quarter-sized coins/packages, you first select the cheapest, hand it over and subtract it from the asking price, then package the remaining ones.
This also can be generalised: whenever the price requires a particular denomination (i.e. it is an odd multiple of that denomination); while packaging that denomination you remove the cheapest one first, subtracting it from the price.  By the time you get to the dollar stage, the price will then be a whole number of dollars.)

Comment: The Wikipedia article ought to explain it like this. Thank you.

Comment: well written, i agree with @jrodatus, having an example like this would have been better in the wikipedia article.

Comment: @mwfearnley please add this to Wikipedia page

Comment: What is the benefit of this over sorting all of your coins by numismatic value and then taking the first X number of coins that add up to $4? If you are at $3.50, and the next coin is a dollar, then just select the next half dollar with the lowest numismatic value instead.

Comment: Nice question.  I guess that's essentially a "greedy algorithm" approach...  But let's say you value all your coins roughly the same, and we put lower denominitions before higher ones (we can tweak the values to ensure this happens) - then you will find yourself preferring two half-dollars (which will be roughly twice as valuable to you) over one whole dollar.

Answer (score 2):

I find the coin analogy unhelpful. You might too. More intuitive for me is to consider a set of rods of various lengths in powers of two: 1/4, 1/2, 1, 2, 4, 8, .... Each rod has a different price. You need to spend the least money on rods and yet span some exact distance X.

With any combination of these rods, you can only /exactly/ span a distance which is diadic, that is "which has factors only of two in its denominator", ie has a terminating binary representation after the point. You can't span 1/5 or 4 3/7 because no finite number of rods matches such distances exactly, there will always be a little left over.

So assuming you have do cover a diadic X, what rods do you use? Think about the smallest binary fraction used in your distance X. If X is 13 3/128 then that's 1/128. That's the level of accuracy you need.

a. If all your rods are bigger than 1/128 then you're stuffed. None of your rods are fine enough to make that last 1/128th. Bad luck.

b. If 1/128 is the smallest kind of rod you have, you're going to have to use at least one of them. There's no choice to go that extra tiny distance: you're going to use one. So may as well buy the cheapest 1/128 rod now. Then you can solve the remaining slightly smaller problem (13 1/64) with the remaining rods.

c. If your smallest rod is tinier than 1/128 (say 1/512) then it's possible that you will use them, but only an even number of them. If you use an odd number, you'll have some tiny amount (here 1/512) left over and whatever you do with the bigger rods can't get rid of that extra little bit and you are stuffed. So you're either gonna use none of them or an even number. If you end up using two, you'll end up using the cheapest two. If you end up using four, you'll end up using the cheapest four, and so on.

So you'll use them in pairs. If you take the cheapest two -- say they cost 5p and 7p -- then if you use them, then you'll use them, effectively, as if they're a single 1/256 piece costing 12p. So take them out of the 1/512 pile and consider them as if a 12p 1/256 piece along with all the other 1/256 pieces. The leftover third 1/512 piece, the most expensive one, is useless, it won't be used for the reason above, it is too fine and will leave over that tiny fraction.

Now we're done with the 1/512 pile, you can now consider the 1/256 pile, which is now the smallest and maybe has a proper 1/256 (say costing 8p) in it, and also our "package" of two 1/512s (costing say 12p). You can then package these up in a pair using the arguments above. It has a cost of 20p and equivalent to a 1/128 piece.

You've not committed to using any of these packages yet, you just know that if you do, you'll use the whole package. And you carry on, up the sizes, making the problem smaller each time, either by reducing the total number of pieces by packaging, or by reducing the target.

So eventually, you will reach your target, or prove that you can't.

The most important thing is to remember that when you build a package you're not, at that point, committing to use it, you're just saying /if/ you do, then you'll use the rods inside as a unit.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't lend itself to a very short explanation; have you read the [Wikipedia page?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package-merge_algorithm)

Comment: yes i read wikipedia.but it is unclear.when we package coins then we merge which list with this?

Comment: I find an algorithm  
Package-Merge  Algorithm(I, X){S is empty; 
for all  d, Ld list  of  items having width 2^d; 
while  X  >  0  loop 
minwidth =  the smallest term  in diadic expansion of X;
ifI=0then //is empty 
return  “No  solution.” ;
else 
d=the minimum  such that  L is not empty;
r=2^d;
if  r > minwidth then 
return  “No  solution.” 
else  if  r = minwidth then 
Delete the minimum  weight ;
X= X -  minwidth ;
end  if 
Pd+1=PACKAGE(Ld) ;
discard Ld ;
Ld+l=MERGE(pd+1,Ld+1); 
end  if 
end  loop 
return  “S  is the optimal  solution.”

Comment: *what is Ld+1 in above algorithm?why we discard Ld when it mybe  have one coins that have value=minwidth?